# Inserir autor e descrição imagem.Latex

Tags: latex

Como consigo colocar o autor abaixo da imagem e uma descrição acima .Da forma mostrada na figura?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote `caption` e então usar `\caption{}` quantas vezes quiser. Para determinar a posição da legenda vai seguir a ordem na qual você escreve o código. Assim, para uma legenda em cima e outra em baixo:

```
\caption{}
\includegraphics{}
\caption*{}
```

Detalhe que no segundo `\caption{}` eu adicionei um `*` para não numerar a legenda.

**Exemplo**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% pacotes para legenda
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Taxonomia de Jogos Sérios}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
\caption*{Fonte: Laamarti, Eid e El Saddik (2014, tradução nossa)}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Para além da elegante solução do @Willian, relembro que é possível escrever LaTeX dentro
do ambiente figura, com o conteúdo que desejares...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Taxonomia de Jogos Sérios}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}\\
 Fonte: Laamarti, Eid e El Saddik (2014, tradução nossa)
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra opção:

Quando utilizei essa mesma estrutura, o meu texto da "Fonte" não ficou quebrada, como se tivesse iniciado na última linha após o final da figura (Não usei o `\\` ao final da função `\includegraphics`. Então pra resolver isso, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
\caption{Taxonomia de Jogos Sérios}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
 \legend{Fonte: Laamarti, Eid e El Saddik (2014, tradução nossa)}
\label{fig:test}
```

Utilizei a função

> \legend

, ficou tão "normatizado" e alinhado, como deveria ficar.